# Entity Framework Core dbcontext scaffold not generating classes

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a Sqlite3 database.  I have checked that it has tables in it, and that it can be read.

I run the following:

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Datasource=db.sqlite3" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite -f
```

It generates the dbContext.cs file, but there are no tables in it.  I have tried including the `-t table_name` option, and it did not change the results.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure `db.sqlite3` is copied to the output directory (e.g. `bin\Debug`). Connection string paths are relative to the same directory they would be at runtime.

```json
{
  "buildOptions": {
    "copyToOutput": [
      "db.sqlite3"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  It was the relative path.